# What happened to Korah's third co-conspirator?

Tags: numbers

Numbers 16 begins (ESV):

> Now Korah the son of Izhar, son of Kohath, son of Levi, and Dathan and Abiram the sons of Eliab, and On the son of Peleth, sons of Reuben, took men

They rebelled and lost. The Lord punished them:

> 23 And the Lord spoke to Moses, saying, 24 “Say to the congregation, Get away from the dwelling of Korah, Dathan, and Abiram.”
>   25 Then Moses rose and went to Dathan and Abiram, and the elders of Israel followed him. 26 And he spoke to the congregation, saying, “Depart, please, from the tents of these wicked men, and touch nothing of theirs, lest you be swept away with all their sins.”

Korah, Dathan, Abiram, their families, and 250 people total died.

On the son of Peleth isn't mentioned by name after the first verse. What happened to him? Was he one of the 250 (but not named, unlike other two) or did he stop being part of the rebellion or something else?

Answer (score 3):

There is no Scriptural reference for Peleth, other than 1 Chron, 2:33,

> **And the sons of Jonathan; Peleth, and Zaza. These were the sons of
>   Jerahmeel.**

In researching this question, I found a midrash(rabbinic explanation) that describes how the wife of On son of Peleth saved her husband from the rebellion of Korah; contrarily, the wife of Korah was destroyed with her husband.

You can find the midrash [here.](http://jwa.org/encyclopedia/article/wife-of-on-ben-pelet-midrash-and-aggadah)

Answer (score 0):

I found something that said Peleth and Pallu were the same person when trying to find the descendants of Reuben. On may have stayed at the tabernacle when everyone was summoned. Remember that Dathan and Aviram didn't come when Moshe called them. It is interesting that his name is not mentioned like the others but I would assume he was killed by the fire at the tabernacle.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).